# Unfortunately project name has stopped when pressing back button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

when i am in count activity , and i want to return to menu activity , I am getting an error "Unfortunately project name has stopped" when pressing back button .

### This is the error log:

```
03-09 14:13:33.767: E/Trace(619): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.projetandroid/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.example.projetandroid.compteur.onOptionsItemSelected(compteur.java:56)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-09 14:14:05.537: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### This is my AndroidManifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.projetandroid"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="17"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >



            <activity
                android:name="com.example.projetandroid.splash"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity> 

            <activity
                android:name=".Count"
                android:label="Count" >

            </activity> 

              <activity
                android:name="com.example.projetandroid.Menu"
                android:label="Menu" >

            </activity>


        </application>

    </manifest>
```

### This is My count Activity

```
 package com.example.projetandroid;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class count extends Activity {
        Button btnadd,bsubtract ;
        TextView text;
        public static int Count=0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      bsubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);  
      text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      text.setText("Your Total is "+Count);


      btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Count++;
            text.setText("Your Total is "+Count);
        }
    });

      bsubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Count--;
                text.setText("Your Total is "+Count);
            }
        });

        }
// the method responsible for back button 
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case android.R.id.home:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(compteur.this,Menu.class);
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    }
```

### This is my Menu activity :

```
    package com.example.projetandroid;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class Menu extends ListActivity {
    String Classes[]={"Manuel Count","example1","example2"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Classes) );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Class cs = null;
            try {



                 if(Classes[position]=="Manuel Count")
                {
                    Classes[position]="count";
                }

                cs = Class.forName("com.example.projetandroid."+Classes[position]);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this ,cs );
        startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
```

### This is My splash activity my first activity

```
package com.example.projetandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class splash extends Activity  {

    MediaPlayer media;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread Timer = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                try{

                     media =  MediaPlayer.create(splash.this,R.raw.theme);
                    media.start();
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this , Menu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }   
        };
        Timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        media.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: Try overriding `onBackPressed()`

Comment: what i can write in onBackPressed() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported the wrong Menu class.

Your Manifest declares:

```
com.example.projetandroid.Menu
```

But you imported:

```
import android.view.Menu;
```

Either change the declaration to match the import or vice versa. It's usually a good idea to make your class names more unique to avoid this kind of issue.

Instead of Menu try MyMenu.